# Decode sentence representation derived from SentenceTransformer

Tags: python, text, bert-language-model, sentence-transformers

Is it possible to decode a sentence representation derived from SentenceTransformer back to a sentence?

See example from the [documentation](https://www.sbert.net/)

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
model = SentenceTransformer('paraphrase-MiniLM-L6-v2')

#Our sentences we like to encode
sentences = ['This framework generates embeddings for each input sentence',
    'Sentences are passed as a list of string.',
    'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.']

#Sentences are encoded by calling model.encode()
embeddings = model.encode(sentences)
```

i would like to decode the representation to get the sentence

```
embedding = [[-1.76214352e-01  1.20600984e-01 -2.93624014e-01 -2.29858071e-01
  -8.22928399e-02  2.37709314e-01  ... 3.39985073e-0]]
sentence = model.decode(embedding)
print(sentence)
```

```
'This framework generates embeddings for each input sentence'
```

Comment: Looking at the architecture as described in the paper, no

Comment: Hi Marat, can you provide, if possible a short explanation of why?

Comment: There is no decoder on Figures 1, 2.

Comment: Alright. but would it be possible to design my own decoder and use it on the output of SentenceTransformer? Is there an obvious reason why that would be a bad idea?

Comment: although not completely impossible, pooling layer makes it very hard